# Close Internet Explorer msg box. FindWindowEX function? childHWND?

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, ie-automation, vba

I'm looking for the solution to close IE browser message box, using Internet Automation in VBA. See attached photo of the screen.  I am not considering keypress event as a good way to do it. 
However I found piece of the code which "smells good" for a solution of this problem.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/d1a556b7-54db-4513-bafd-f16ed000f9ac/vba-to-dismiss-an-ie8-or-ie9-message-from-webpage-popup-window?forum=ieitprocurrentver

Do you know how to use FindWindowEX function? I am stuck at this part:

```
If childHWND <> 0 Then SendMessage childHWND, BM_CLICK, 0, 0
    End If
```

I cannot find childHWND and enter this conditional. I appreciate your help and suggestions!

[image]